# This SQL query over JDBC crashed the JVM, why?

Tags: java, sql, jvm

I have omitted the actual select fields for brevity, the following query works:

```
Select * FROM my_db WHERE CONVERT(Termination_Date, SQL_VARCHAR) IS NULL OR (Rehire_Date > Termination_Date)";
```

This works fine.

This one literally crashes the JVM:

```
Select * FROM my_db WHERE CONVERT(Termination_Date, SQL_VARCHAR) IS NULL OR (Rehire_Date > Termination_Date AND CONVERT(Termination_Date, SQL_VARCHAR) IS NOT NULL)";
```

I realize that the second query is wrong, but I ran it, and it crashed the JVM instead of a SQL exception. This is repeatable every time. Why?

[image]

Comment: Looks like it generated an `OutOfMemoryError` due to retrieve too much data (but I'm not really sure about this). Doesn't your application has a log where will notify about these events?

Comment: On the first statement call? It might be a memory leak multiplied by several calls.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the program stops responding.  If you lock up the program long enough with a very long query, this error can occur.

The best way around this is to use a background thread to run the query and not run such long queries.

Just in case it is a JVM bug, I would make sure you have the latest patch of Java for your version.  However, given the program works except for one query I suspect you are tying up the GUI event thread for too long.